# Arduino Heroku request

Tags: python, http, heroku, arduino, httprequest

I am trying to make a request from an Arduino to a [Heroku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) application. All it returns is Heroku's 404 page. So I wrote a similar script in Python, and it works fine.

#### Arduino code:

```
char serverName[] = "ruby-coffee-maker.herokuapp.com";

...

if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("connecting...");

    if (client.connect(serverName, 80)) {
        Serial.println("connected");

        // Make a HTTP request
        client.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
        client.println();

        // Wait for response
        delay(100);

        // If data can be read from te server, print it
        while (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read();
            Serial.print(c);
        }

        Serial.print("Done");
        client.stop();
    }
    else {
      // If you didn't get a connection to the server:
      Serial.println("connection failed");
    }
}
```

#### Python code:

```
import httplib

h = httplib.HTTPConnection("ruby-coffee-maker.herokuapp.com")

h.request("GET", "/")

r = h.getresponse()
data = r.read()

print r.status, r.reason, "\"" + data + "\""

h.close()
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you compared the request sent by your Arduino-code, compared with the Python-code? Based on my understanding of HTTP/1.1, you need to add a Host header filed to the GET request. See 5.1.2 [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html).

Sorry, I just saw that you use HTTP/1.0 in your Arudino request, is there a particular reason for that? Even though the Host-filed is not required for 1.0, you might be required to include it anyway (for example some proxies require it to be present).

Comment: Actually, yes. I was looking through some info on Heroku and it started that they do not support HTTP 1.1. Regardless, adding the host header would possibly fix the issue. Do you know the syntax for that?

Comment: Hm, based on an article I found on their site, they seem to support HTTP/1.1 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing). Also, Python uses 1.1 by default (and insert the host, I see when tcpdumping). Anyway, the host for your request would be ruby-coffee-maker.herokuapp.com, so your request should look something like this: client.print(GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ruby-coffee-maker.herokuapp.com\r\n\r\n". The reason I removed println, is to have control over the line breaks. It might not be needed.

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned and it works like a charm! Many thanks!